# How to include ListBox inside DataGrid control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, listbox

I'm developing a WPF 4 application using MVVM pattern. I have one DataGrid control with columns auto generated and binded with a DataTable object.

My table now is like that:

```
+------------+---------------+---------------+
| Date       | Shop 1        | Shop 2        |
+------------+---------------+---------------+
| 2016-01-01 | 09:00 - 13:00 | N/A           |
+------------+---------------+---------------+
| 2016-01-02 | N/A           | 14:00 - 18:00 |
+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

I need this result:

```
+------------+---------------+---------------+
| Date       | Shop 1        | Shop 2        |
+------------+---------------+---------------+
| 2016-01-01 | 9:00 - 13:00  | N/A           |
|            | 14:00 - 18:00 |               |
+------------+---------------+---------------+
| 2016-01-02 |               | 14:00 - 18:00 |
|            | 9:00 - 10:00  |               |
|            | 12:00 - 14:00 |               |
+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

For each range of hours I need different colors, so I would bind one listbox for each cell of the table.

Actually my XAML code is this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grdScheduler" 
          IsEnabled="False"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
          HeadersVisibility="None" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding SchedulerDataTable, Mode=OneWay}">            
</DataGrid>
```

Please, can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need it to be auto generated column?

Comment: What is the data type of the Shop 1 and Shop 2 DataColumn? Is it an array/list or just a string?

Comment: @LawrenceA.Contreras: Unfortunatelly yes, I need autogenerate columns. I have a list object for Shop1 and Shop2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8b2e94b7-3c44-4642-8acc-851de5285062/bind-datatable-to-wpf-datagrid-using-datagridtemplatecolumn-programatically?forum=wpf) is similar to what you are asking. But I made an example that will fit your question.

You will need to provide a `DataGridtemplateColumn` to your `List<object>` column type. To do that we create an event handler to the AutoGeneratingColumn event of the Datagrid. Yes, you need to write some code behind but this won't break anything in your MVVM world. You can write a code behind or you can implement your own datagrid custom control if you want a cleaner way to do it. 
Now inside the DataGrid.Resource, we have a DataTemplate called ListTemplate. This will be the cell template of every `List<object>` columns.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grdScheduler" 
      IsEnabled="False"
      AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
      HeadersVisibility="None" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding SchedulerDataTable, Mode=OneWay}"         
      AutoGeneratingColumn="grdScheduler_AutoGeneratingColumn">
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListTemplate">
      <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

For every column of type `List<object>` you need to use a DynamicDataGridTemplateColumn and use the *ListTemplate* as the CellTemplate. In this code block you can also use different templates for every generated columns if you want to.

```
    private void grdScheduler_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.PropertyType == typeof(List<object>))
      {
        DynamicDataGridTemplateColumn dgTemplateCol = new DynamicDataGridTemplateColumn();
        dgTemplateCol.CellTemplate = (sender as DataGrid).FindResource("ListTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        dgTemplateCol.ColumnName = e.PropertyName;
        e.Column = dgTemplateCol;
      }
    }
```

And here's the code for DynamicDataGridTemplateColumn.

```
  public class DynamicDataGridTemplateColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn
  {
    public string ColumnName
    {
      get;
      set;
    }

    protected override System.Windows.FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
      // The DataGridTemplateColumn uses ContentPresenter with your DataTemplate.
      ContentPresenter cp = (ContentPresenter)base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);
      // Reset the Binding to the specific column. The default binding is to the DataRowView.
      BindingOperations.SetBinding(cp, ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, new Binding(this.ColumnName));
      return cp;
    }
  }
```